# Rust: concurrency error, program hangs after first thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust

I have created a simplified version of my problem below, I have a `Bag` struct and `Item` struct. I want to spawn 10 threads that execute `item_action` method from Bag on each `item` in an `item_list`, and print a statement if both item's attributes are in the bag's `attributes`.

```
use std::sync::{Mutex,Arc};
use std::thread;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Bag{
    attributes: Arc<Mutex<Vec<usize>>>
}

impl Bag {
    fn new(n: usize) -> Self {
        let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        for _ in 0..n {
            v.push(0);
        }

        Bag{
            attributes:Arc::new(Mutex::new(v)),
        }
}

    fn item_action(&self, item_attr1: usize, item_attr2: usize) -> Result<(),()> {

        if self.attributes.lock().unwrap().contains(&item_attr1) ||
        self.attributes.lock().unwrap().contains(&item_attr2) {

            println!("Item attributes {} and {} are in Bag attribute list!", item_attr1, item_attr2);
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Item{
    item_attr1: usize,
    item_attr2: usize,
}

impl Item{
    pub fn new(item_attr1: usize, item_attr2: usize) -> Self {
        Item{
            item_attr1: item_attr1,
            item_attr2: item_attr2
        }
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let mut item_list: Vec<Item> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10 { 
        item_list.push(Item::new(i, (i+1)%10));
    }

    let bag: Bag= Bag::new(10); //create 10 attributes

    let mut handles = Vec::with_capacity(10);

    for x in 0..10 {
        let bag2 = bag.clone();
        let item_list2= item_list.clone();

        handles.push(
            thread::spawn(move || {
                bag2.item_action(item_list2[x].item_attr1, item_list2[x].item_attr2);
            })
        )
    }

    for h in handles {
        println!("Here");
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

When running, I only got one line, and the program just stops there without returning.

```
Item attributes 0 and 1 are in Bag attribute list!
```

May I know what went wrong? Please see code in [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=982789636dc417d27b7f453c38e4cf67)

**Updated**:

With suggestion from @loganfsmyth, the program can return now... but still only prints 1 line as above. I expect it to print 10 because my `item_list` has 10 items. Not sure if my thread logic is correct.

I have added `println!("Here");` when calling `join` all threads. And I can see `Here` is printed 10 times, just not the actual log from `item_action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because Rust is not running your

```
if self.attributes.lock().unwrap().contains(&item_attr1) ||
    self.attributes.lock().unwrap().contains(&item_attr2) {
```

expression in the order you expect. The evaluation order of subexpressions in Rust is currently undefined. What appears to be happening is that you essentially end up with

```
const condition = {
  let lock1 = self.attributes.lock().unwrap();
  let lock2 = self.attributes.lock().unwrap();
  lock1.contains(&item_attr1) || lock2.contains(&item_attr2)
};
if condition {
```

which is causing your code to deadlock.

You should instead write:

```
let attributes = self.attributes.lock().unwrap();
if attributes.contains(&item_attr1) ||
   attributes.contains(&item_attr2) {
```

so that there is only one lock.

Your code would also work as-is if you used an [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) or [`ReentrantMutex`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/0.3.8/parking_lot/struct.ReentrantMutex.html) instead of a `Mutex` since those allow the same thread to have multiple immutable references to the data.

Comment: Hi @loganfsmyth, with your code, the program can return now but it still prints only 1 line. I expect it to print 10 since I have 10 items in `item_list`. Is my thread logic correct?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some investigation. Apparently, all 10 threads run but they don't print anything from `item_action` function...

Comment: after one thread, the `attributes` in `Bag` becomes all zeros

Comment: `attributes` doesn't become all zeroes, you are creating it with all zeroes to begin with. Your output prints 2 lines because those are the only 2 lines where one of the arguments is `0` and thus `.contains()` returns `true` for only those 2.

Comment: you are right! Silly me! Thank you for the solution!